# How to make moving background in Android

Tags: android, android-view

I want Moving my application background in Android. but I do not know how to do it or what software I use to do.
My mean moving background such as this application : [Timely Alram](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely).
What methods do you offer? I am grateful your guides. <3

Comment: what about http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create an animated background easily you can 
start learning to use AndEngine: 
http://www.andengine.org/blog/

There's also a tutorial for a little game here:
https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/andengine-simple-android-game-tutorial/

You can follow this tutorial and adapt the code to do the animated background.

Hope it helps.